# Imagemagick rails image composition adding unwanted white background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagick

I have the following code:

```
 begin

      big_image = Magick::ImageList.new

      #this is an image containing first row of images
      first_row = Magick::ImageList.new




      #adding images to the first row (Image.read returns an Array, this is why .first is needed)
      first_row.push(Magick::Image.read(Rails.root.join("app","assets","images","logo.png")).first)

      if @model.avatar.exists?
        image = Magick::Image.read(@model.avatar.path).first

        image = image.resize_to_fit("450", "401")


        first_row.push(image)

      end


      #adding first row to big image and specify that we want images in first row to be appended in a single image on the same row - argument false on append does that
      big_image.push (first_row.append(false))


      fileName = @model.id.to_s + ".png"
      big_image.append(true).write(Rails.root.join("app","assets","images","shared_logo",fileName))



    rescue => e
      puts "Errors! -- #{e.inspect}"
    end
```

The codes puts two image on the same row. The images are png. The problem is that the second image has an height less than the first one. Image magick fill the remaining part with an unwanted white background. I want to keep the transparency on the combined image.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
manipulate! do |img|
  img.combine_options do |c|
    c.background    "transparent"
    c.gravity       "center"
    c.extent        "450x401"
  end
end
```

This is for RMagick if I'm not mistaken, the names might be slightly different (although I think combine options is using mongrifies methods?).

Comment: @Kerby82 ok then